# How to pass jquery method

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to pass a method using jquery?

My code is as follows:

```
var BodySwitcher = {

    initBodySwitcher : function(){
        $(document).on("click", ".bodySwitcher", function() { 
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            this.ajaxCall(action, null, this.showBody());
        });
    },

    ajaxCall : function(action, data, callback){
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert('Error');
            },
            success: function(data){         
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    },

    showBody : function(data){
        $("#body_container").empty();
        $("#body_container").html(data);
    }


};
```

What i want to do is to re-use my ajax function by passing all the parameters on it including the callback method/function..

THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see is the use `this` inside the click event handler to refer to the `BodySwitcher` object.

Try

```
var BodySwitcher = {
    initBodySwitcher: function () {
        var self = this;
        $(document).on("click", ".bodySwitcher", function () {
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            //this here refers to the `bodySwitcher` element not the BodySwitcher object
            self.ajaxCall(action, null, $.proxy(self.showBody, this));
        });
    },

    ajaxCall: function (action, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    },

    showBody: function (data) {
        $("#body_container").empty();
        $("#body_container").html(data);
    }
};
```